# Get sql server DB to github

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, git, github

I have two SQL Servers Instances, one for DEV and one Production. 
I would Like to be able to follow changes made on views, stored procedures etc on both DB and be able to push modification from Dev DB to Prod DB.

Can you please help me to get my databases on github? 
How can my modification on ssms syncrhonise automatically to git repo?
Is it possible to do pull requests between both sql instances? without copy pasting manually.

I am not able to get a paid software for this task.
Thank you

Comment: You can't pull/push changes from a source control model directly to a SQL Instance. You need to create a Database Project and source control that. Then define a *good* migration/deployment process from Dev to Production. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @Larnu, the free VS 2019 community edition includes SSDT database projects and git integration. The key is to keep the database under version control and employ a merging and branching strategy similar to other application code. That will allow you to build the database from a given branch and publish (i.e. deploy) the database dacpac build artifact to the instance(s) you want to upgrade.